# 'Body' empty when opening default email client in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, email-client

I am creating a chrome extension wherein the some content should be sent as email on a button click. I am trying to invoke the default email client using the below code :

```
function sendlist(tabs) 
{

  var contents = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) 
  {
        if(!tabs[i].pinned)
      contents += tabs[i].url + '\n\n\n';
  }
    var link = "mailto:?&body="+contents;
    alert(link);
    chrome.tabs.create({url: link});

}
```

The content of variable 'link' needs to be send as Body of the email. **strong text**If i use `'chrome.tabs.create({url:link});`  then it will invoke the default email client but the body part will be empty.**

Is there any way to open the default email client say 'Outlook' and get the values of 'link' in  body part of that email?

Comment: At least encode the `contents` variable: [`encodeURIComponent(contents)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred due to wrong formatting of the mail headers.
The correct syntax would be :

```
var link = "mailto:?body="+escape(contents);
```

Using the `escape()` function formatted the required content properly. Also, I removed the `&` before the body header.